# Filling Dataframe so rows are populated consistently

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv files in a folder, the first of which looks like this:

df1

```
Value  Count
1      10
2      1
3      2
4      15
5      8
```

and the second of which is like this:

df2

```
Value  Count
1      5 
2      22
3      13
4      16
5      11
6      18
```

I want `Value` in each of them to match.  Essentially I want to turn df1 into this:

```
   Value  Count
    1      10
    2      1
    3      2
    4      15
    5      8
    6      0
```

even though a `Value` of 6 doesn't exist in df1 I want it populated with zero.

I am reading in my files like this:

```
pth=r'C:\pathway'
for f in os.listdir(pth):
    df=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth,f)
```

and I tried adding this on:

```
df=df.append({'Value': '6', 'Count': '0'}, ignore_index=True)
```

but this adds the new row to df2 as well which I want to avoid.

I have about 20 csv files in a folder and I just want the `Value` to match in all of them and be filled with 0 if a particular `Value` is not present.

Comment: Can you make it more explicit which are df1 and df2 in your code? I can see that you read a csv, but where is the destination DataFrame?

Comment: there is no actual `df1` and `df2`, since it is being read in a loop everything is just called `df`.  This is the line that dictates that, `df=pd.read(csv(os.path.join(pth,f)`.  As of now there is no destination frame. Each file then as of now is just called `df`

Comment: I eventually want to merge all the `df`by appending a list and using something like this: `df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Value'], how='outer'), list1)` but first I need to make the `Value` consistent between the files

Comment: Try creating a destination DataFrame before the loop (only with the column names) than use @piRSquared 's answer to combine them.

Comment: Forgive me but I am unfamiliar how to do that, also, I do not want to manually type df1, df2, df3, df4 etc.  which I believe I would need to do with that solution

Comment: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Value', 'Count'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do [using `reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html). First you set the index of each df equal its own Value column. Then reindex based on the larger (df2).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create dfs and change their indices to use the `Value` column.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.arange(1,6), 'Count': [10, 1, 2, 15, 8]})
df1.index = df1.Value
df1.drop(['Value'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.arange(1,7), 'Count': [5, 22, 13, 16, 11, 18]})
df2.index = df2.Value
df2.drop(['Value'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Reindex with desired fill_value
df1 = df1.reindex(index=df2.index, fill_value=0)

       Count
Value
1         10
2          1
3          2
4         15
5          8
6          0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from glob import glob
filenames = glob('C:/pathway/*.csv')

def rfile(fn):
    return pd.read_csv(fn, index_col=0)

dfs = [rfile(fn) for fn in filenames]
idx = dfs[0].index
for i in range(1, len(dfs)):
    idx = idx.union(dfs[i].index)
```

`idx` is now your index that is a union of all indices in all files.  `reindex` any one of the individual dataframes in the following manner to get what you want.

```
df = dfs[0].reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: since it is being read in a loop they are all actually called `df`.  I just used `df1` and `df2` as the example

Comment: the edit returns 1 dataframe with a sum of the `Count` for each `Value` from every individual csv file, not what I am actually looking for.

Comment: I added a `.csv` to the end of path.  This is actually a bad way to control for file inputs.  I have to guess what is and isn't in the directory you are using.  You said there were only two files, correct?  Anyway, hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: I actually have about 20 files, I just used the two to try and simplify.  The directory has 20 files of which there is unmatching data within `Value` as in my  `df1` and `df2` example.  I want to keep the dataframes seperate, but make all of them match based on `Value`.  So `df1` doesn't have a `Value` of 6 so I want it added in populated and `Count` assigned to 0.  Another frame may not have a `Value` of 7 which would mean 7 would need to be added to `Value` and `Count` populated with 0.  Its a little hard to explain for me.